# FillRectangle over Child Controls Inside a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, panel, picturebox

I want to draw a rectangle on Mousedown for Mousearea Select on my panel:

```
    private void flowLayoutPanel1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseDown)
        {
            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.DodgerBlue);
            Graphics g = this.flowLayoutPanel1.CreateGraphics();
            g.FillRectangle(brush, selection);
        }
    }
```

Selection here has the rect area on which Mouse has been dragged upon.

But if I put Form-Elements, like a Picturebox , on this panel,
my rectangle is behind this button.
But I want to render it in the front.

What can I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: winforms? I am afraid you can't

Comment: Hello chouaib , what makes you to think so ?

Comment: 1. You're creating new `Graphics` instance when you must be using `e.Graphics`. 2.brush instance has to be disposed, `using` statement would be better. 3. You can't do that, children are drawn  over the parent. not behind it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel , agreed with #1 and #2. I was able to achieve drawing over both Panel(Parent) and Picturebox (Child Controls) with **ControlPaint.FillReversibleRectangle**  [ MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.fillreversiblerectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). But it caused lot of Flickering. So i suppose it might not be impossible.

Comment: To make this work, you would have to overlay something, like a `Panel` made transparent, over the entire client space.  Then draw on that overlay.  But that would make interaction with the underlying form messy.  So this overlay would have to be dropped in on-demand, drawn upon, and then removed when interaction with the form is needed.  It's time to question why you are doing this...

Comment: @DonBoitnott Rightly So , Basically i have Panel having Collection of Pictureboxes. I want to MultiSelect this PictureBoxes by Dragging on Mouse Left Click which would create Rectangle to Indicate Pictureboxes Selected.Now i am folllowing the approach you have indicated above.

Comment: Given what you just said, I would take a different approach.  Why not draw _everything_ on the Panel?  Don't put any controls on the panel.  Draw the images yourself.  That way, when you draw the selection rectangle, it will be over everything else on that same Panel.  I you need real controls, such as Button, ComboBox, etc. then this will not work.